# How can I disable a User Account from the CLI with Mac OS X Server?

Tags: mac-osx-server, opendirectory, mac-osx

Is there any possible solution to disable a User from the CLI e.g. over SSH?
There has to be a dscl command for that. Or is there a dsAttrTypeStandard attribute that I can set accordingly?

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 8):

## For all OS X accounts

`pwpolicy` doesnt work for local accounts on OS X client. BUT *You can* use the dscl command to directly edit these authentication settings. This method is guaranteed to work for user-level OS X accounts (Guest, admin and other regular accounts which you would see listed on the login window). With this approach it doesn't matter whether the account is managed with OS-X Server / LDAP account. This method also works for all OSX System Accounts (which you would otherwise disable their login shells).

Here's how:

```
# Read the AuthenticationAuthority key
dscl . -read /Users/username AuthenticationAuthority

AuthenticationAuthority: ;Kerberosv5;; \
username@LKDC:SHA1.41BE28E3B64EB62A42D0673968B9591DE18210F5; \
LKDC:SHA1.07264456235E49D45C4B99FC9549FC366CE32343; ; \
ShadowHash;HASHLIST:<SALTED-SHA1>
```

### Disable

If not already disabled, then append `DisabledUser` to this key's value. With a semicolon for the field seperator. Excess / empty `; ;` fields are ignored.

```
dscl . -append /Users/username AuthenticationAuthority ";DisabledUser;"
```

### Check

To check an account's enabled / disabled status:

```
dscl . -read /Users/username AuthenticationAuthority | grep DisabledUser
```

For OSX System accounts: These accounts don't have an `AuthenticationAuthority` key to begin with. Therefore to check their enabled / disabled status is determined by whether the `UserShell` attribute has a valid login shell. So check the shell when `AuthenticationAuthority` doesn't exist.

### Enable

To re-enable the user account we just remove `DisabledUser` sub-string from the AuthenticationAuthority entry. We use then use the `dscl . -create` cmd and write-back the whole thing.

```
dscl . -read /Users/username AuthenticationAuthority | \
sed 's/AuthenticationAuthority: //;s/DisabledUser//g;s/[; ]*$//' | \
xargs dscl . -create /Users/username AuthenticationAuthority
```

Get the AuthenticationAuthority credentials for all users:

```
dscl . -list /Users AuthenticationAuthority
```

System accounts: Just remember that a system account must also have a valid login shell.

Answer (score 6):

This works in 10.5 and 10.6 on LDAP/OD accounts:

```
pwpolicy -a diradmin -u ajohnson -setpolicy "isDisabled=1"
```

Or for local accounts:

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/ajohnson UserShell /usr/bin/false
```

Replace ajohnson with the short username of the user you wish to disable.

To re-enable simply set "isDisabled=0" instead of 1. Or in the case of local accounts to any shell in `/etc/shells`

`pwpolicy` example is from page 62 of the [User Management Documentation (Snow Leopard)](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/User_Management_v10.6.pdf) or Page 106 of the [Command Line Administration Leopard](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/command_line_admin_v10.5.pdf) manual.

Answer (score 1):

We have some OSX clients authenticating from a Linux LDAP server. What worked for me was setting a user's loginShell attribute to /usr/bin/false. This seems to prevent both SSH and graphical logins.